# Evaluating 3f2 hypergeometric function using Euler integral

Tags: calculus, hypergeometric-function

Consider the  [generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html):
$$ {_3F_2}\left(1,\frac12,\frac12;\ \frac76,\frac{11}{6};\ \frac{4z}{27}\right) $$

I know it can be done with the beta integral as shown below: [What is $_3F_2\left(1,\frac32,2;\ \frac43,\frac53;\ \frac4{27}\right)$ as an integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091474/what-is-3f-2-left1-frac32-2-frac43-frac53-frac427-right-as-an-int?noredirect=1&lq=1)

the harder problem is how to evaluate the 3f2 expression using the Euler integral . this hard because the integrals are elliptic , involve fractions of 1/3 or 1/6, and there are double integrals. I am guessing one makes  substitutions,  but there are many possible approaches to this.

Comment: I am faced to a very similar question in these links https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4872230/how-to-prove-this-difficult-double-integral-identity and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466853/how-to-prove-these-identities-for-log2-based-on-3f-2-integrals It is very difficult, I do not have an answer already.