# How to prove this difficult double integral identity?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

In [this MathOverflow link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463436/are-these-fast-convergent-series-for-log2-log3-and-log5-already/) -originally posted here in MSE- I have placed 4 fast hypergeometric-type series for logarithm constants. I could prove 3 of them by using a Beta function approach transforming the series to integrals that are evaluated straightwise. One of them, Eq.(2), remains un-proven.

Applying the same concepts, but using a multivariate extension of the Beta Function, I have put this series in integral form, $$\begin{equation*}\log(2)-\frac{9607}{13860}=\frac{1}{1024}\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^2(1-y)^3\,y^3\,Q(y)}{(1-r(x,y))^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y}}\tag{1}\label{1}\end{equation*}$$ where $$r(x,y)=\frac{x(1-x)^2(1-y)^3\,y^3}{512}$$ and $Q(y)$ is the fifth degree polynomial $$Q(y)=\frac{1}{1944}y^5-\frac{11}{7776}y^4+\frac{569}{69120}y^3+\frac{953}{69120}y^2-\frac{95}{3456}y+\frac{17}{48}$$ I wonder if some smart ad-hoc variable substitution can reduce the factor $(1-r(x,y))^{\frac{3}{2}}$ to transform the integral in Eq.(1) to a simpler form in order to be evaluated and prove this $\log(2)$ equality.

Obviously a proof based on Residues and Complex Analysis or a CAS assisted evaluation (Mathematica, Maple, Sage, etc.) including some specialized packages and Add-Ons (Rubi, MultiIntegrate from JKU-RISC, others) is accepted and welcome, as well as, if it is necessary, the use of Higher Functions (Shifted Jacobi Polynomials, Elliptic, Meijer-G, Fox-H, others).

**Q:** Is it possible to get a proof of Eq.(1)?