# Proving that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^{-5k}(6k+1)((2k-1)!!)^3}{4(k!)^3} = {1\over\pi}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, pi, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals

While trying to prove that $$(1)\qquad x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^{-5k}(6k+1)((2k-1)!!)^3}{4(k!)^3} = 1 \implies x=\pi$$

I got to a point, using W|A, where I have to prove that $$\color{red}{(2)\qquad \pi = -\frac{8 \left (\sqrt{16-3 K\left ({1\over4} (2-\sqrt{3})\right )^2\, _3 F_2\left ({3\over2}, {3\over2}, {3\over2};\,2, 2;{1\over4}\right )}-4\right )}{\left (3\, _3 F_2\left ({3\over2}, {3\over2}, {3\over2};\,2, 2;\,{1\over4}\right )\right )}}$$

*Where $K(x)$ is the complete elliptic K function, and $_xF_y(a_1 ... a_p;b_1 ... b_q; z)$ is the generalized hypergeometric function.*

***IMPORTANT:*** As user153012 pointed out, there is likely an error in $(2)$, as I translated it from mathematica to Latex by hand, so I'll just post the mathematica query so that there is no misunderstanding:

> -8 (-4 + Sqrt[16 - 3 EllipticK[(2 - Sqrt[3])/4]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2, 3/2, 3/2}, {2, 2}, 1/4]]))/(3 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2, 3/2, 3/2}, {2, 2}, 1/4])

Here's a [LINK](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%28-8%20%28-4%20%2B%20Sqrt[16%20-%203%20EllipticK[%282%20-%20Sqrt[3]%29%2F4]%5E2%20HypergeometricPFQ[%7B3%2F2%2C%203%2F2%2C%203%2F2%7D%2C%20%7B2%2C%202%7D%2C%201%2F4]]%29%29%2F%283%20HypergeometricPFQ[%7B3%2F2%2C%203%2F2%2C%203%2F2%7D%2C%20%7B2%2C%202%7D%2C%201%2F4]%29) to the query (*If W|A show a message similar to "Wolfram|Alpha doesn't know how to interpret your input", just recompute the query by either refreshig the page or pressing the orange and white $=$ sign*).

I will be correcting this error asap.

Is there a way to prove $(2)$ to be true, or another way to prove $(1)$ to be true (by eliminating the double factorial? I haven't had any success in doing this myself.)?

Thanks.

Comment: For me the RHS of $(2)$ is not $\pi$. It is $3.0135849404\dots$

Comment: @user153012 I've addressed the issue as best I can at the moment. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Did you try using a flamethrower?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I... I Don't get it...

Comment: Like in the movie "The Thing", only that the thing here is that summation.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff (+1 for Carpenter reference)It got nothing on Ramanujan’s infinite series of ${1\over\pi}$... :P

Comment: **Hint:** $~(2k-1)!!\cdot(2k)!!=(2k)!~$ and $~(2k)!!=2^k~k!~$ Then use a trick similar to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426389).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^{-5k}(6k+1)((2k-1)!!)^3}{4(k!)^3} = \frac{1}{\pi}\tag1$$

or its equivalent form,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2k)!^3}{k!^6}\frac{6k+1}{(2^8)^{k+1/2}} = \frac{4}{\pi}\tag2$$

and the similar,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(2k)!^3}{k!^6}\frac{6k+1}{(2^9)^{k+1/2}} = \frac{8}{\pi}\tag3$$

belong to the Ramanujan-type family,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2k)!^3}{k!^6}\frac{Ak+B}{(C)^{k+1/2}} = \frac{1}{\pi}\tag4$$

where $A,B,C$ are algebraic numbers. There are only *four* formulas such that $A,B,C$ are integers. The complete list can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0013).

The ***general*** case has already been proven by either the Borweins, Berndt, or Guillera. For the specific details, their papers can be found online. Raymond Manzoni has given a list in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/600552/4781).